# Having trouble with Firebase Auth Android

Tags: android, firebase

I have launch my app and when I clicked Share button then my apps stopped working, error show like this :

```
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Invalid scheme specified: https:/findingyou2.firebaseio.com/
                                                                      at com.firebase.client.utilities.Utilities.parseUrl(Utilities.java:23)
                                                                      at com.firebase.client.Firebase.<init>(Firebase.java:155) 
                                                                      at com.robby.findingyou.LocationShareReceiver.SetAlarm(LocationShareReceiver.java:116) 
                                                                      at com.robby.findingyou.LocationServices.onStartCommand(LocationServices.java:27)
```

this is LocationShareReceiver has contain error with Firebase :

```
app = Application.instance();
    Log.v("application", app.toString());
    if(app != null) {
        app.setSharingStatus(true, context);
    }
    Firebase.setAndroidContext(context);
    mFirebaseRef = new Firebase("https:/findingyou2.firebaseio.com/");
    if(mFirebaseRef != null) {
        authData = mFirebaseRef.getAuth();
        if(authData != null)
            mUserID = authData.getUid();
    }
    if(mFirebaseRef != null && authData != null) {
        mFirebaseRef.child("users").child(mUserID).child("expiration").setValue(expiration);
    }
```

And this error too from LocationServices.java :

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
    int interval = Integer.parseInt(intent.getStringExtra("frequency"));
    int d = Integer.parseInt(intent.getStringExtra("duration"));
    long expiration = System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000*60*d;
    Log.v("duration", d + "");
    alarm.SetAlarm(LocationServices.this, interval, expiration);
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}
```

that's error because of what? Please help me with this

Comment: You need two `/` after `https:`: `https://findingyou2.firebaseio.com/`

Comment: oh yeah that's it , so that little thing is making me crazy of whole time. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

URISyntaxException, because your url is in wrong format

Just replace

```
https:/findingyou2.firebaseio.com/
```

to

```
https://findingyou2.firebaseio.com/
```

Comment: Why I can't see that :D my mistake, sorry and Thanks a lot!